rocky9: getting freeipa and fips mode to work together
Adding some rocky9 systems to an existing freeipa-based network. For some select hosts I have to enable fips mode. This breaks freeipa and I can't login:
Aug 11 19:48:04 host.domain ldap_child[2152]: Failed to initialize credentials using keytab [MEMORY:/etc/krb5.keytab]: KDC has no support for encryption type. Unable to create GSSAPI-encrypted LDAP connection.

I can make freeipa work by changing the default crypto via update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:AD-SUPPORT but this makes fips unhappy:
# fips-mode-setup --check
FIPS mode is enabled.
The current crypto policy (DEFAULT:AD-SUPPORT) neither is the FIPS policy nor is based on the FIPS policy.
Inconsistent state detected.

Is it possible to get these things working in harmony?

I had a similar situation and the only way I got things working was to have FIPS enabled on all the IPA servers. Not sure whether it is possible to enable FIPS on existing servers without breaking them. And I worry how things will go when I come to upgrade in the future or when a new FIPS standard is issued.
